# problem with upload laravel project to subfolder

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel

i have uploaded my laravel project to this domain http://acceyou.com in folder named share but when i try to open it the browser give me this error

**Internal Server Error**

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@acceyou.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

The steps i have done are :

1. uploaded the file to folder public_html/share.
2. moved the .htaccess from public_html/share/public folder into public_html/share.
3. changed the name of file public_html/share/server.php into public_html/share/index.php.
4. changed the function in public_html/share/vendors/laravel/framework/src/illuminate/foundation/helpers.php
   the function was like this

   ```
   function asset($path, $secure = null)
   ```

   {
   return app('url')->asset($path, $secure);
   }
   changed to this:

   ```
   function asset($path, $secure = null)
   ```

   {
   return app('url')->asset("public/".$path, $secure);
   }

Comment: I don't see any error in that domain

Comment: why are you putting it in a subfolder in the first place? why are you renaming `server.php` to `index.php`? .. the index file is the `index.php` file in `public` ... why are you changing vendor files?

Comment: http://acceyou.com/share/home

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your PHP version, since Laravel 7.x required PHP version >= 7.2.5 in their [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x#server-requirements).
2. Check your Laravel debug log in /storage/logs to see what the problem is. It it doesn't help then try to see Apache or Nginx log.
3. You should not attemp to move any files in /public folder to the root folder, it will work but your system will also exposed with some potential threats. Use .htaccess file to properly configure it if you are using Apache.